# CSS and not() using childrens

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply a attribute to all *input[type=text]* elements but exclude certain elements.
The elements to exclude does not have any class but their parent parent does.

The HTML looks like

```
<tr class="filters">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="aName">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="anotherName">
    </td>
        ...
</tr>
```

I tried this CSS:

```
input[type=text]:not(tr.filters > td > input[type=text])
{
    min-width:400px;
}
```

but it does not work.
Is it not possible to use not() in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with `:not()` as a CSS selector. The [`:not()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) accepts only a simple selector (which means exactly one `type`, `.class`, `#id`, `[attribute]` *or* `:pseudo-class` selector). Combinators like , `>` and `+` aren't allowed.

The default value of `min-width` is zero, so you can simply use an overriding rule instead and set it to that:

```
input[type="text"] {
    min-width: 400px;
}

tr.filters > td > input[type="text"] {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your selector would work just fine in jQuery though, as it implements its own [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) that accepts that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this?

```
tr:not(.filters) td input[type=text]
{
    min-width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because there may be `input[type="text"]`s that aren't in any tables.